# Python Server & Client won't communicate

Tags: python, tcp, server, client

I've been following examples on a server and client communication within Python but I cannot get the server to constantly listen for new messages, print them and send them back for the client to print it as well. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Server code:

```
#Imports
import socket

#Define socket address
TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0'  # consider all incoming IPs 
TCP_PORT = 5000  # port# communicating with the client
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024  # buffer size for receiving data

#Create socket    IPv4            TCP
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print "Socket created"


s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

s.listen(20)
print "Waiting for a Cli_socket..."

#Wait for Cli_sockect
while True:
    while True:
        # accept Cli_sockection 
        Cli_sock, addr = s.accept()
        print "Cli_sockected with " + addr[0] + " " + str(addr[1])
        # get message from client
        message = Cli_sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print message
        # check that there is a message   
        if not message:
            break
        # send message to client
        Cli_sock.send(message)
        print "Sent message"

    s.close()
    print "Socket Closed"
```

Client code:

```
# a simple client socket
import socket

# define socket address
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'  # ip of connecting server
TCP_PORT = 5000  # port communicating server
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024  # buffer size receiving data


# create socket IPv4 & TCP protocol
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print "Socket created successfully."

# connect to server
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
print "Established connection with the server."
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

while True:
    print ("Message to send:")
    message = raw_input()
    s.send(message)
    print "Message sent to server: %s." % message
    print ("Message Recv:%s\n" % data)
```

Comment: What is the behavior that you see?  How doesn't it work?  Are there stack traces or other information to share that is more specific?

Comment: The client gets stuck at the line 28 with data receiving and doesn't get to the print statement. No error occurs. If I put the data = s.recv after the s.send(message) in the while loop of the Client, the loop sends the message but stops after reaching the data = s.recv(Buffer_size) again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is waiting for data from the client before sending anything:

```
Cli_sock, addr = s.accept()
print "Cli_sockected with " + addr[0] + " " + str(addr[1])
# get message from client
message = Cli_sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

Your client is waiting for data from the server before sending anything:

```
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
print "Established connection with the server."
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

Thus both wait for each other to send data but nobody does. That's why it hangs.

Comment: Did this and then found out the Cli_sock, addr = s.accept() was crashing the code after the second time around the loop in server.py. It works now.